# writing lines from many text files in sub directories to csv using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to derive some statistics out of a large amount of data files that all reside in their own folder. Using python, I want to create a single csv file, look for the data files starting from a root folder at a fairly high level (new folders are added all the time), and write a row with some key values from every file.

I've done this before using the `os.walk()` method combined with `writerows()`, but it's giving me problems this time around. When I run the code below, (with a file called XY.txt in my D:/temp/ folder) I get an error that reads: *'unexpected unindent'* at the line that reads `wr = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n',dialect='excel')`

I have moved the indentation around but that just moves the mentioned error with it. Can anybody advise me on how to achieve the desired row writing?

```
import csv, os, math

fname = 'Output.csv'

f = open(fname, 'w') #truncate existing file or generate new one
f.write("count>0.7\n")
merged_files = list()


# look for data files, in sub-folders down from D:/temp
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/temp', topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith('XY') and name.endswith('.txt'):
            try:
                fp = open(root+'/'+name)
                #create a list for storing relevant data from .txt file
                csvRows = list()
                for line in fp:
                    content = line.split()
                    size = float(content[3])
                    #count lines with value over 0.7 in fourth column
                    if size > 0.7: 
                        total1 = total1 + 1
                fp.close()
            finally:
                csvRows = [total1]
                merged_files.append(csvRows)

# write new row to file.
wr = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n',dialect='excel') 
wr.writerows(merged_files)

f.close()
```

I'm setting this up with rows so I can extract many more items from the .txt file, but I have not included those in the code above for clarity.

*updated code to reflect answer: now the `try:` sequence is ended with the `finally:` statement, in which all the information collected during the `for` loop is written to a line.

Comment: You have a  `try` without an `except` or `finally` clause.

Comment: Don't concatenate folders and files if you call os. Use os.path.join: `os.path.join(root, name)`.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I used the os.path.join and it works fine. However, is there a functional reason to do so? The previous code had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

*try* attempts to run the block of code, if it fails then it runs the block of code in *except*. There is an optional *finally* clause which runs irrespective of whether the code in *try* succeeds.

For example, the function in the following code snippet will return 2 when executed

```
def checktry():
   try: 
       return 1
   finally:
       return 2
```

I would recommend an *except* clause which would print out a helpful message if the code fails.

```
except Exception as inst:                                                       
    print(inst)
```

Reference : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. The script works wonderfully now. I will update the question page for future reference.

Comment: No problem @skleijn Please upvote the answer if you find it helpful